# XDEBUG not working on certain cakephp Netbean projects

Tags: php, cakephp, netbeans, xdebug

If I create a new project in netbeans and add a line break, Xdebug works perfectly with no issues. But for a cakephp project I have, if I add a line break (even in the index.php file) xdebug ignores it. I am trying to figure out whats going on.

## xdebug setup

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so"
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.auto_trace = 1
```

I am using MAMP and Netbean for my tools. even when I use `xdebug_break()` it still skips. I do have a virtual host set up but not sure if that has anything to do with it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had really hard time figuring this one out:
in NetBeans' project preferences, you must set the Web root to the app's webroot directory to get breakpoints working.

On a different note I've had NetBeans crashing when there were variables on the watch list that were not in scope when a breakpoint was triggered.

Comment: thanks alot, I actually pointed it to webroot, but thanks alot.